# How to Pass a Parameter Back Through a Subscribed Event Handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates, tcpclient

Salutations fellow coders,

I'm writing a tcpClient in a .NET standard 3.1 console program. The client class is connecting to the event-channel of an industrial printer, meaning the messages sent from the server are sporadic at best.

I currently have a thread running, which automatically retrieves server-messages parallel to the execution of the main program. During the retrieval process, the following event is triggered:

```
/*####################### myTcpClass #######################*/
public event EventHandler OnMessageReceived;
private void CallOnMessageReceived()
{
    var handler = this.OnMessageReceived;
    handler?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

When this event is triggered, I would like to send the message *back* to the subscribed method, allowing the message to be used outside of the class. What I have in mind is something like this:

```
/*###################### MAIN PROGRAM ######################*/
// creation of tcp client, auto-connects on creation
myTcpClass myTcp = new myTcpClass(ip:"123.123.123.123", port:22171);
// subscribe event
myTcp.OnMessageReceived += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e, String receivedMessage)
{
    // do something here with received message...
};
```

For the life in me, I can't figure out how to return a value to the subscribed method, and my searches online have so-far returned `null`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First, your event should be named `MessageReceived` and the method that raises it should be named `OnMessageReceived`. The method also ought to be `protected virtual`. Finally, the current instance, i.e. `this`, should be passed as the first argument to `Invoke`, so that object will be the `sender` in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start by reading [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html), which explains how to write your own events and pass data both ways.

When you declare your event as type `EventHandler`, the second parameter to the event handler is type `EventArgs` and that type has no properties to pass data either way. If you want to pass data to and/or from the event handler then you need to declare your own type that inherits `EventArgs` and adds the required property(ies). You then declare your event as type `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` where `TEventArgs` is specified as your type.

For example, you might declare this class:

```cs
public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // Data sent from the object raising the event to the object handling the event.
    public string Output { get; }

    // Data sent from the object handling the event to the object raising the event.
    public string Input { get; set; }

    public SomeEventArgs(string output)
    {
        this.Output = output;
    }
}
```

and then use it in a class like this:

```cs
public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomeEvent;

protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(SomeEventArgs e)
{
    SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, e);
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    var e = new SomeEventArgs("Hello");

    OnSomeEvent(e);

    Console.WriteLine(e.Input);
}
```

That event might be handled like this:

```cs
private void SomeObject_SomeEvent(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Output);

    e.Input = "Goodbye";
}
```

All the data is passed in both directions via the `e` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the abridged version of relevant information from your blog! To be clear, is the "DoSomething" function working as the internal trigger function (ie. in a property setter), instead of the "OnSomeEvent" function?

Comment: @RobotFox, OnSomeEvent method is the dedicated method to raise the event, similar to want you'll find throughout the .NET Framework. That gets called any time you want to raise the event and it gets overridden in derived classes of you want to change the behaviour. You then call that method from a property setter or wherever else you might want to raise the event from.